# Query with linq using a where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities

Okay so I've already asked this question but I've narrowed it down and am now able to word it better.

I have a sql database and an asp.net mvc project with entity frameworks. I already figured out how to query the database and display all contents. But now I need to query the database and only display the rows where column "a" is greater than or equal to column "b".

Edit: datatypes in both columns are int

Here is the query I need

```
Select * 
from Inventory 
Where quantity <= statusLow
```

Comment: Better you should give the DB Query to understand it better `I already figured out how to query the database and display all contents`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as shown below.

```
 using (var db = new yourContext())
  {
     var result = db.Inventory.Where(a=> a.quantity <= a.statusLow).ToList();
  }
```

You can learn more about [**LINQ to Entities**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399367(v=vs.110).aspx) here.

Comment: The only variation to this was to make a.quantity a.quantity.value same for statuslow

Answer (score 2):

```
var context = new MyContext();

var query = context.Inventory.Where(p=> p.quantity <= p.statusLow); // write the statement to query

var result = query.ToList(); // obtaining the result, trigger the database
```